# How to put data vertically in TextView in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Please let me know, how can I put strings seperated by line, vertically in an `TextView`?

I am scanning a QR Code and fetching the data integrated in the code, I want it shown vertically in an edittext, but it is coming horizontally in edit text.

Below is the xml code for EditText

```
<TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:id="@+id/edt"        
       android:gravity="top"/>
```

below is my activity code

```
finalOutput= new StringBuffer();
qrValueArray = new ArrayList<String>();
String line= System.getProperty("line.separator");       
String[] valueOfQRAfterSplit = intentQrScanValue.split(";");    


for(int j = 0; j < valueOfQRAfterSplit.length; j++) {
    if(j==0){
        finalOutput.append(valueOfQRAfterSplit[j].toString());
     }else{
        finalOutput.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + valueOfQRAfterSplit[j].toString());
     }
}
ed1.setText(finalOutput);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),finalOutput, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The thing is in Toast data is coming vertically, while in EditText it is coming horizontally and i have to scroll horizontally to see all the data.

Comment: Did you set your TextView's multiline property to true? Try setting it to true.

Comment: No. I couldn't find any such property.

Comment: Thanks YuDroid, I achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom `TextView` for that. There are quite a few open implementations available if you google it. Here's one that I've used in the past:

http://code.google.com/p/dobroreader/source/browse/src/org/anonymous/dobrochan/widget/VerticalTextView.java

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using this example. Basically you have to create your own `TextView` class that extends from the standard `TextView`:

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/796

I hope this helps and is what you're looking for!